# Enable and Disable drag jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, drag

I have got chart in container and checkbox for dragging function, enable and disable works, but if i click for second time enable checkbox it doesn't work. I don't know where is mistake. Below is jiddle url and IF statement function Thanks for suggests

http://jsfiddle.net/dmmqwr6d/

```
function EnableDrag(checkboxvalue) {
  if (checkboxvalue == true) {
    $("#chartdiv").draggable("enable");
  } else {
    $("#chartdiv").draggable("disable");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply providing the wrong argument to the `EnableDrag()` function. The value of the checkbox never changes, it is the checked state (or property) of the element that changes.

Simply change the html where you define the checkbox from

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="EnableDrag(this.value);" checked>Chart drag
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="EnableDrag(this.checked);" checked>Chart drag
```

I've updated your jsfiddle here to reflect that: http://jsfiddle.net/dmmqwr6d/1/